# Truncate an array without copying it?

Tags: java

In Java, is there a way to truncate an array without having to make a copy of it? The common idiom is `Arrays.copyOf(foo, n)` (where the new array is n elements long). I don't think there is an alternative, but I'm curious as to whether there is a better approach.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An array's length in Java cannot be altered after initialization, so you're forced to make a copy with the new size. Actually, the length parameter of a Java array is declared as final, so it cannot be changed once it's set.

If you need to change an array's size, I'd use an ArrayList.

Comment: +1, Arraylists are very nice if you're trying to manipulate the size of things or remove elements efficiently.

Comment: @Brian ArrayList does not remove elements efficiently. You should use something like LinkedList for that.

Answer (score 6):

I was thinking about it some more... and just for kicks, how about something like the below.

**Note:** This is just a "can it be done?" intellectual exercise in Java hacking. Anybody who attempts to actually use this idea in production code will deserve all the pain that will undoubtedly follow.

```
public class Foo
{
    private static byte[] array = new byte[10];

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception
    {
        Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) field.get(null);
        Field arrayField = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("array");
        long ptr = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(arrayField);
        // doesn't work... there's gotta be a way though!
        unsafe.reallocateMemory(ptr, 5);
        System.out.println("New array size is: " + array.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. An array is allocated as a contiguous block of memory, and I can't imagine that there is any way of releasing a part of that block.

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly: No, There isn't, as far as I know. A Java array is a fixed-size data-structure. The only way to "logically" resize it is create a new array and copy the wanted elements into the new array.

Instead: You could (possibly) implement a class which wraps an array into a collection and uses a "size" variable to logically reduce the length of the array without actually copying the values. This an approach has limited utility... The only case I can imagine where it's practical is when you're dealing with a huge array, which just can't be copied because of memory limitations.

Copying an array is relatively inexpensive time-wise... unless you're doing it millions of times, in which case you probably need to think up an algorithm to avoid this, and not waste your time mucking around with a "variable length array".

And of course... you could just use an ArrayList instead. Yes?